# how to use gsoap to call several services on the client side without conflict

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gsoap

I recently use gsoap to call web services, but once I use not only one service, the gsoap generates "soapH.h" "soapStub.h" for every service.So how can I handle these files? I tried to just simply change the second "soapH.h" and "soapStub.h" to "soapH2.h", "soapStub2.h", but it doesn't work. I'm totally confused.    Is there anyone who has used it?  please help me, thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple .wsdl files the simplest way to handle this is to just call wsdl2h once with all of the .wsdl files:

```
wsdl2h -o myHeader.h a.wsdl b.wsdl
```

You should then get a single myHeader.h file to pass to soapcpp2 and the code that get generated will cover all of the services.  Section 8 of the gsoap documentation covers this.

Comment: but why I get this: "Can not open the file myHeader.h"

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more context here, can you update your question to show the commands your entering, the output from gsoap and what files are getting created?